# How can I extract data from source code into my text fields?

Tags: javascript, html, yahoo-finance

I am trying to write a page that takes the value added in the text1 box to make the URL from which the data will be extracted.

If I were to open the DOM on a webpage and run

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(140px)--pnclg D(tbc)")[0].innerText
```

It gives me the Total Revenue for the company who the url is for.

And by changing the number in the [] gives a different value from the table.

How can I get that number to display in the textbox "revenue"

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Manipulations</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function fn1()
    {
        document.getElementsByClassName('document.getElementsByClassName("Ta(c) Py(6px) Bxz(bb) BdB Bdc($seperatorColor) Miw(120px) Miw(140px)--pnclg Bgc($lv1BgColor) fi-row:h_Bgc($hoverBgColor) D(tbc)")[0].innerText');
        const url = new url ("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ text1 +"/financials?p="+ text1)
        
        
    }


    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>

    <input id="text1" placeholder="Stock code">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onClick="fn1">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <input id="revenue" placeholder="Revenue" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="grossprofit" placeholder="Gross Profit" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="netprofit" placeholder="Net Profit" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="dividendyield" placeholder="Dividend Yield" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="pricebook" placeholder="Price/Book" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="pricesales" placeholder="Price/Sales" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="currentratio" placeholder="Current Ratio" readonly="readonly">
    <br><br>
    <input id="totaldebt" placeholder="Total Debt" readonly="readonly">


    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: I don't see where you've attempted to do that. What have you tried?

Comment: You're sort of asking two things. Is the question about extracting data from a string, or about how to update an input's value?

Comment: If you just need form data to become a URL with parameters, just make a full HTML form with 'method' set to 'get'. It works to create the params in the URL by default. It's how forms work out of the box. If you are trying to do something different your question needs more clarity.